# Email HTML table renders correctly in Gmail but fails in Outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

I'm trying to convert a simple Web HTML into an Email HTML file. I was able to convert it into table structure which renders properly in Gmail but fails in Outlook.

The height and width of all the corresponding rows and columns are correct. I'm not able to figure out the reason why it breaks in Outlook.

Below is a screenshot of the working case from Gmail:

[image]

Below is a screenshot of the failing case from Outlook :

[image]

Fiddle for the HTML code : [HTML file](https://jsfiddle.net/9zLx68ke/)

```html
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <center>
         <div align="left">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="131" width="750" border="0" style="padding-left:0; padding-right:0; padding-top:1; padding-bottom:1; table-layout:fixed; word-wrap:break-word;">
               <tbody>
                  <tr height="0">
                     <td width="1"></td>
                     <td width="5"></td>
                     <td width="102"></td>
                     <td width="2"></td>
                     <td width="2"></td>
                     <td width="4"></td>
                     <td width="30"></td>
                     <td width="12"></td>
                     <td width="47"></td>
                     <td width="1"></td>
                     <td width="2"></td>
                     <td width="21"></td>
                     <td width="1"></td>
                     <td width="1"></td>
                     <td width="2"></td>
                     <td width="12"></td>
                     <td width="1"></td>
                     <td width="2"></td>
                     <td width="2"></td>
                     <td width="1"></td>
                     <td width="2"></td>
                     <td width="19"></td>
                     <td width="12"></td>
                     <td width="36"></td>
                     <td width="12"></td>
                     <td width="4"></td>
                     <td width="8"></td>
                     <td width="7"></td>
                     <td width="2"></td>
                     <td width="4"></td>
                     <td width="6"></td>
                     <td width="9"></td>
                     <td width="1"></td>
                     <td width="1"></td>
                     <td width="41"></td>
                     <td width="1"></td>
                     <td width="1"></td>
                     <td width="43"></td>
                     <td width="2"></td>
                     <td width="24"></td>
                     <td width="6"></td>
                     <td width="4"></td>
                     <td width="4"></td>
                     <td width="3"></td>
                     <td width="1"></td>
                     <td width="12"></td>
                     <td width="7"></td>
                     <td width="3"></td>
                     <td width="27"></td>
                     <td width="1"></td>
                     <td width="67"></td>
                     <td width="5"></td>
                     <td width="7"></td>
                     <td width="6"></td>
                     <td width="1"></td>
                     <td width="4"></td>
                     <td width="27"></td>
                     <td width="6"></td>
                     <td width="21"></td>
                     <td width="9"></td>
                     <td width="29"></td>
                     <td width="1"></td>
                     <td width="2"></td>
                     <td width="1"></td>
                     <td width="1"></td>
                     <td width="1"></td>
                     <td width="3"></td>
                     <td width="3"></td>
                     <td width="1"></td>
                     <td width="1"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr height="4">
                     <td valign=top rowspan="2" width="1"></td>
                     <td valign=top colspan="67" width="747">
                        <div>
                           <p style="padding-top:0px;padding: 0px;word-wrap: break-word;margin: 0px;color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space: nowrap;padding-left:0px;font-size: 9pt;padding-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;font-family: Arial;margin-bottom:0px;text-align: left;padding-right:0px;"> <span style="color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space:nowrap;font-size: 9pt;font-family: Arial;text-align:left;">-</span> </p>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td valign=top colspan="2" rowspan="2" width="2"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr height="4">
                     <td valign=top colspan="67" width="747">
                        <div>
                           <p style="padding-top:0px;padding: 0px;word-wrap: break-word;margin: 0px;color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space: nowrap;padding-left:0px;font-size: 9pt;padding-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;font-family: Arial;margin-bottom:0px;text-align: left;padding-right:0px;"> <span style="color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space:nowrap;font-size: 9pt;font-family: Arial;text-align:left;">-</span> </p>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr height="9">
                     <td valign=top colspan="2" rowspan="3" style="background-color:#072460;" width="6"></td>
                     <td valign=top colspan="25" rowspan="3" style="background-color:#072460;" width="338">
                        <div>
                           <p style="padding-top:0px;padding: 0px;word-wrap: break-word;margin: 0px;color: rgb(255,255,255);padding-left: 8px;font-size: 16pt;padding-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;font-family: Arial;margin-bottom:0px;text-align: left;padding-right:0px;"> <span style="color: rgb(255,255,255);font-weight: bold;font-size: 16pt;font-family: Arial;text-align:left;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit </span><span style="color: rgb(255,255,255);font-weight: bold;font-size: 16pt;font-family: Arial;text-align:left;">consectetur </span> </p>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td valign=top colspan="42" style="background-color:#072460;" width="405"></td>
                     <td valign=top rowspan="9" width="1"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr height="16">
                     <td valign=top colspan="3" style="background-color:#072460;" width="13"></td>
                     <td valign=top colspan="12" style="background-color:#072460;" width="139">
                        <div>
                           <p style="padding-top:0px;padding: 0px;word-wrap: break-word;margin: 0px;color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space: nowrap;padding-left: 8px;font-size: 10pt;padding-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;font-family: Arial;margin-bottom:0px;text-align: left;padding-right:0px;"> <span style="color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space:nowrap;font-size: 10pt;font-family: Arial;text-align:left;">Vivamus tincidunt:</span> </p>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td valign=top style="background-color:#072460;" width="4"></td>
                     <td valign=top colspan="12" style="background-color:#072460;" width="140">
                        <div>
                           <p style="padding-top:0px;padding: 0px;word-wrap: break-word;margin: 0px;color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space: nowrap;padding-left: 8px;font-size: 10pt;padding-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;font-family: Arial;margin-bottom:0px;text-align: left;padding-right:0px;"> <span style="color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space:nowrap;font-weight: bold;font-size: 10pt;font-family: Arial;text-align:left;">Vestibulum </span> </p>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td valign=top style="background-color:#072460;" width="4"></td>
                     <td valign=top colspan="9" style="background-color:#072460;" width="97">
                        <div>
                           <div style="overflow: hidden;word-break: break-word;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;">
                              <span style="color:rgb(255, 255, 255);direction:ltr;font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:100%;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;white-space:normal;">
                                 <div style="text-align:right;"><a href="https://www.lipsum.com/feed/html" style="color:rgb(255, 255, 255);font-size:10pt;text-decoration:underline;">Lorem Ipsum</a></div>
                              </span>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td valign=top colspan="4" style="background-color:#072460;" width="8"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr height="27">
                     <td valign=top colspan="42" style="background-color:#072460;" width="405"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr height="16">
                     <td valign=top colspan="30" rowspan="4" style="background-color:#072460;" width="357"></td>
                     <td valign=top colspan="13" style="background-color:#072460;" width="143">
                        <div>
                           <p style="padding-top:0px;padding: 0px;word-wrap: break-word;margin: 0px;color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space: nowrap;padding-left: 8px;font-size: 10pt;padding-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;font-family: Arial;margin-bottom:0px;text-align: left;padding-right:0px;"> <span style="color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space:nowrap;font-size: 10pt;font-family: Arial;text-align:left;">Nulla convallis:</span> </p>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td valign=top colspan="12" style="background-color:#072460;" width="140">
                        <div>
                           <p style="padding-top:0px;padding: 0px;word-wrap: break-word;margin: 0px;color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space: nowrap;padding-left: 8px;font-size: 10pt;padding-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;font-family: Arial;margin-bottom:0px;text-align: left;padding-right:0px;"> <span style="color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space:nowrap;font-weight: bold;font-size: 10pt;font-family: Arial;text-align:left;">Aliquam amet</span> </p>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td valign=top style="background-color:#072460;" width="4"></td>
                     <td valign=top colspan="9" style="background-color:#072460;" width="97">
                        <div>
                           <div style="overflow: hidden;word-break: break-word;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;">
                              <span style="color:rgb(255, 255, 255);direction:ltr;font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;line-height:100%;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;white-space:normal;">
                                 <div style="text-align:right;"><a href="https://www.lipsum.com/feed/html" style="color:rgb(255, 255, 255);font-size:10pt;text-decoration:underline;">Phasellus</a></div>
                              </span>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td valign=top colspan="4" rowspan="4" style="background-color:#072460;" width="8"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr height="16">
                     <td valign=top colspan="13" style="background-color:#072460;" width="143">
                        <div>
                           <p style="padding-top:0px;padding: 0px;word-wrap: break-word;margin: 0px;color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space: nowrap;padding-left: 8px;font-size: 10pt;padding-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;font-family: Arial;margin-bottom:0px;text-align: left;padding-right:0px;"> <span style="color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space:nowrap;font-size: 10pt;font-family: Arial;text-align:left;">Donec eget velit:</span> </p>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td valign=top colspan="22" style="background-color:#072460;" width="241">
                        <div>
                           <p style="padding-top:0px;padding: 0px;word-wrap: break-word;margin: 0px;color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space: nowrap;padding-left: 8px;font-size: 10pt;padding-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;font-family: Arial;margin-bottom:0px;text-align: left;padding-right:0px;"> <span style="color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space:nowrap;font-weight: bold;font-size: 10pt;font-family: Arial;text-align:left;">Nunc metus</span> </p>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr height="16">
                     <td valign=top colspan="13" style="background-color:#072460;" width="143">
                        <div>
                           <p style="padding-top:0px;padding: 0px;word-wrap: break-word;margin: 0px;color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space: nowrap;padding-left: 8px;font-size: 10pt;padding-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;font-family: Arial;margin-bottom:0px;text-align: left;padding-right:0px;"> <span style="color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space:nowrap;font-size: 10pt;font-family: Arial;text-align:left;">Duis rhoncus enim:</span> </p>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td valign=top colspan="22" style="background-color:#072460;" width="241">
                        <div>
                           <p style="padding-top:0px;padding: 0px;word-wrap: break-word;margin: 0px;color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space: nowrap;padding-left: 8px;font-size: 10pt;padding-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;font-family: Arial;margin-bottom:0px;text-align: left;padding-right:0px;"> <span style="color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space:nowrap;font-weight: bold;font-size: 10pt;font-family: Arial;text-align:left;">Vivamus </span> </p>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr height="16">
                     <td valign=top colspan="13" style="background-color:#072460;" width="143">
                        <div>
                           <p style="padding-top:0px;padding: 0px;word-wrap: break-word;margin: 0px;color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space: nowrap;padding-left: 8px;font-size: 10pt;padding-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;font-family: Arial;margin-bottom:0px;text-align: left;padding-right:0px;"> <span style="color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space:nowrap;font-size: 10pt;font-family: Arial;text-align:left;">Praesent laoreet:</span> </p>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td valign=top colspan="22" style="background-color:#072460;" width="241">
                        <div>
                           <p style="padding-top:0px;padding: 0px;word-wrap: break-word;margin: 0px;color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space: nowrap;padding-left: 8px;font-size: 10pt;padding-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;font-family: Arial;margin-bottom:0px;text-align: left;padding-right:0px;"> <span style="color: rgb(255,255,255);white-space:nowrap;font-weight: bold;font-size: 10pt;font-family: Arial;text-align:left;">Pellentesque </span> </p>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr height="3">
                     <td valign=top colspan="69" style="background-color:#072460;" width="749"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr height="4">
                     <td valign=top colspan="2" style="background-color:#072460;" width="6"></td>
                     <td valign=top colspan="63" style="background-color:#072460;" width="735">
                        <div>
                           <p style="padding-top:0px;padding: 0px;word-wrap: break-word;margin: 0px;color: rgb(7,36,96);white-space: nowrap;padding-left:0px;font-size: 9pt;padding-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-top:0px;font-family: Arial;margin-bottom:0px;text-align: left;padding-right:0px;"> <span style="color: rgb(7,36,96);white-space:nowrap;font-size: 9pt;font-family: Arial;text-align:left;">-</span> </p>
                        </div>
                     </td>
                     <td valign=top colspan="4" style="background-color:#072460;" width="8"></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      </center>
   </body>
</html>
```

Can you please let me know how to make it correct and consistent across both Gmail and Outlook?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding the background color to your table rather than at the td level.

Comment: Hi @Syfer, I'm trying to convert the web html to email html algorithmically. Contrary to the example given, there can be multiple segments inside the table with different background colors . Can you please provide a probable reason for this unusual behaviour? I suspect some attribute or css style for this but I'm unable to find it.

Comment: You are using `colspan` and `rowspan` which can throw columns off if they don't equate to the right number (per row). Personally I stay away from col and row span, even if code is generated, as it's very hard to maintain.

Comment: I did consider `colspan` and `rowspan` as a potential cause for the problem. I did the calculations for every row and it turned out to be correct. All the cells are properly occupied by the elements. 8 out of 10 conversions are working perfectly except for some specific use cases. The algorithm uses the concept of rowspan and colspan for converting the div based structure into table structure. I don't think these attributes can be avoided. I was hoping if there could be some another attribute or Css Style which could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check all your `<td>` elements have the background color.

Alternatively, you can just wrap the entire table in another table that has the background-color, like so:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#072460">
    ...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you don't want the top rows to have a color, put a wrapping table in for them with a white bgcolor - or remove them entirely (why are they even there...).